# How can I modify the contents of an public m file in a dynamic library?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made a framework, The files I chose to make public were **.h** and **.m** files. I found that if I modify the contents of the **.m** file directly, it won't take effect. So what should I do to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but in the abscence of other answers let's see if I can help:

> I made a framework

So you wrote some *text* into some files; then you used a tool, probably Xcode, to invoke the *compiler*, which interpreted that text as Objective-C and produced machine code in another file, and then constructed a framework bundle for you.

> The files I chose to make public were .h and .m files. I found that if I modify the contents of the .m file directly, it won't take effect.

So now you edit your text file, and what do you expect to happen - not sure. Do you expect the framework code to change? If so aren't you missing a step compared to the above?

> So what should I do to take effect?

Well that depends on what your goal is here. If you want your users to be able to customise your framework in some way then you need to design a method to do that using whatever tools you can when iOS is your target (Apple has rules).

This answer isn't much, but hope it helps.